# Which Master was spying on Rin?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In Fate/Stay Night, in the 2nd Day of the Prologue, Rin takes Archer to the Fuyuki Park where the 4th Holy Grail War ended. While they are there, Rin's Command Spell acts up and because Archer can't sense any Servant, they figure out that another Master is spying on Rin.

Just using logic, I could assume it's not...

- ... Caster, as while she is the Master of Assassin, she is also a Servant and Archer sensed no Servants.
- ... Bazett, as Kotomine had told Rin that 6 of the 7 Masters are ready. While it's revealed in Fate/Hollow Ataraxia that she was Lancer's original Master, at this point, I could assume he had already attacked and stolen her Command Spells
- ... Shinji, as the day before Rin didn't detect the Bounded Field at the school, but the day after she does, which means while she was away from school, Shinji and/or Rider would have been setting it up then.
- ... Shirou, as he wasn't a Master at that point.

So that would leave Ilya or Kotomine. However, I can't be sure if Sakura had created the Book of the False Attendant at this point, or if Kotomine was actually doing his own recon, so I am wondering if there is any source indicating which Master was spying on Rin and Archer at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Caster is the only viable person to be able to use such an underhanded method, via her Far Sight (i.e., her crystal ball).

Shinji is incompetent to the point where he can't even provide his servant with prana, much less do basic magecraft.

Bazett is no longer in the picture by this time do to a certain priest.

Illya has no reason to, because she has Berserker.

It's not Kirei because he is the mediator, so the identities of all the masters would be known to him sooner or later, because all the masters are expected to report in to him.

Only assasin is capable of spying,  but the Assassin of this Grail War is confined to a shrine on a mountain...

Comment: So Caster could disguise herself as a servant from Archer but not as a Master from Rin?